# Databinding with Linq - unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, data-binding, linq-to-entities

Hello everyone and thanks for your interest in helping.

I am having a great difficulty in updating the data of a DataBinding using Linq. I've read a lot and I really didn't find a solution. The code I'm using is this:

```
private void MontaGrid()
{
    var ini = DateTime.Parse(dtIni.EditValue.ToString()).Date;
    var fim = DateTime.Parse(dtFim.EditValue.ToString()).Date.AddDays(1);

    _ctx.programacao.Where(c => c.data >= ini && c.data < fim)
                                                          .OrderBy(c => c.data)
                                                          .ThenBy(c => c.id_programacao)
                                                          .Load();

    programacaoBindingSource.DataSource = _ctx.programacao.Local.ToBindingList();
}
```

The idea is to load the filtered data, bringing only those of interest to the BindingSource.

So, when loading with Load() and assign the data that is already on the machine to the BindingSource using .Local.ToBindingList().

The loading of the first consultation occurs normally. However, when I change the date and redo the command, the data from the previous query does not disappear, they accumulate. If I repeat a larger query even in the period it brings more data and displays. If I shorten the period, the data does not disappear, it remains there.

To be sure of the SELECT being generated by Linq I checked the execution of the call in the XEvent Profiler of the Management Studio of SQL Server and noticed that the generated code is correct.

I tested the BindingSource load on different components and they all present the same situation, which leads me to believe that the problem is in the BindingSource.

I tried to avoid .Local() and took a different approach (code below) but with .ToList() I can't include new records: when I use it and apply context.SaveChanges() I don't get an error message and the new one record not saved.

```
programacaoBindingSource.DataSource = _ctx.programacao.Where(c => c.data >= ini && c.data < fim)
                                                                  .OrderBy(c => c.data)
                                                                  .ThenBy(c => c.id_programacao)
                                                                  .ToList();
```

I always worked all the CRUD manually with EF + Linq but it is a lot of work and I am now trying to migrate to BindingSource to automate these tasks and due to my inexperience I am having difficulties in this point.

Please, can you guide me?

Comment: You can use a new instance of your ef context for each query so you do not receive everything it has been tracking since instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I cannot create a new instance in each situation. I use the components of DevExpress and they ask that, because of the resources of the components, the instance is maintained throughout the execution of the form.

Comment: Well, you need to get rid of the tracked entities somehow, I haven't read this fully but at a glance [it looks like a good explanation of how to clear cached entities](https://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/)